# On Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a Principal Ideal Domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, principal-ideal-domains

I'm working on a question that asks to consider the ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[x]$.  I need to show that $(x)$ is a prime ideal, show that $(x,7)$ is a prime ideal and use these facts to conclude that $R$ is not a principal ideal domain.

I believe I've gotten to the point where I have shown that both $(x)$ and $(x,7)$ are prime ideals, but is using these facts to conclude that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a principal ideal domain somewhat trivial?  From what I understand, in a principal ideal domain all ideals are principal, i.e., all of the form $(a)$ for some element $a \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$.

Since I have shown that $(x,7)$ is a prime ideal, does this in fact mean that $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ is not a PID?  Or do I need to go further and prove that somehow the prime ideal $(x,7)$ is not equal to some other principal ideal $(a)$?  If so, how could I go about showing that $(x,7)$ is in fact not principal?

Comment: If $(x,7)=(a)$, then $a$ would be a common divisor of $a$ and of $7$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$. There aren't many of those, and you can check none of them yield $(x,7)$, because prime ideals can't be the whole thing. But this just requires you to know that $(x,7)\neq\mathbb{Z}[x]$, so showing it is prime seems like overkill to me.

Comment: I know you're not taking this approach, but it's worth having in your pocket: the Krull dimension of $\mathbb Z[x]$ is $2$, but the Krull dimension of any PID is $1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin - Do you mean that $a$ would be a common divisor of $x$ and of 7?  Either way, I'm not sure how you can come to that conclusion

Comment: @Oderus: If $(x,7)=(a)$, then $x\in (a)$, so $x=ap$ for some $p\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$. So $a$ divides $x$. Symmetrically, since $7\in (x,7)=(a)$, you would have $a|7$. Any element that lies in a principal ideal $(a)$ must be a multiple of the generator, so the generator is a divisor of every element in the ideal.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I understand now - under this reasoning, $a|7$ so either $a = 1$ or $a = 7$, but it cannot be that $a=1$ since otherwise $(a)$ would be the entire ring, hence $a = 7$.  But $7\nmid x$, hence the contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

You know that $(x)$ and $(x,7)$ are prime ideals. Since $7\notin(x)$ we have $(x)\subsetneq(x,7)$. Now suppose that $R$ is a PID. There is $p\in R$, a prime element, such that $(x,7)=(p)$. From $(x)\subsetneq(p)$ we get $p\mid x$ and since $x$ is prime, hence irreducible, $p$ is associated to $x$, so $(x)=(p)$, a contradiction.